# Bash running in sequence from Cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, cron

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
sleep 15 & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait
```

How do I get it to wait for the previous line to finish executing before moving to the next?

It work fine when you call the bash file directly , but when called from **cronjob**, it's executing everything without waiting for the previous one to finish.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, why not simply remove "& wait" to have job one after the other ?

Answer (score 2):

This will work in one after other only, all the below are same:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
sleep 15 & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait


#!/bin/bash
# My first script
sleep 15 
python pythonFileName.py 
python pythonFileName.py 
python pythonFileName.py
```

**`<Command> & wait`**  You wont achieve anything special with this

**&** will take the process in background

**wait** will make parent process to wait for state of child process to change

```
UID       PID   PPID
root     28065 28064  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/bash /home/8zero2/Desktop/b.sh 
root     28067 28065  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/8zero2/Desktop/b.sh
root     28074 28067  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 sleep 15


root     28065 28064  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/bash /home/8zero2/Desktop/b.sh 
root     28067 28065  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/8zero2/Desktop/b.sh
root     28075 28067  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 python pythonFileName.py


root     28065 28064  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/bash /home/8zero2/Desktop/b.sh 
root     28067 28065  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/8zero2/Desktop/b.sh
root     28077 28067  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 python pythonFileName.py


root     28065 28064  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/bash /home/8zero2/Desktop/b.sh 
root     28067 28065  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/8zero2/Desktop/b.sh
root     28074 28067  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 python pythonFileName.py
```

corelate the ppid and pid column, you will notice sequential execution only in both cases

Comment: So is the solution to remove & wait? also , is there anyway to detect errors ? It's still not running the python file , how do u view that process?

Comment: no , it will work with & wait also , i just mean to say its hot adding anything special to code

Comment: In case it is not working , plz tell me thae path of your python script and your bash script